# Jenkins に接続しているスレーブの IP を調べるには？

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins に接続しているスレーブの IP を調べたいです。これは、どうやったら実現できますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Jenkins -> ノード -> 該当スレーブ -> ログ
/jenkins/computer/SLAVENAME/log
```

を表示すると、`JNLP agent connected from /www.xxx.yyy.zzz` のような形で表示されるので、ここから確認できます。

この画面には、 Jenkins に対してログインしている状態で、スレーブのプルダウンからジャンプ可能です。